# Regarding android:configChanges

Tags: android, manifest, screen-orientation

Can anyone explains to me what does `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` mean? I have a book that explains it as follows:

> Line 16 makes sure that screen orientations do not occur when either
>
> • The hardware keyboard is slid open or closed on a device
>
> • The software keyboard is enabled or disabled.

But still I did not get it, it is not clear. Can any one explain it better please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But still I did not get it, it is not clear.

That is because the quoted explanation is *awful*. You need a better book. :-)

Android has the notion of "configuration changes", when the state of the device changes in a way that may cause you to need different resources. Orientation changes (i.e., rotating the screen from portrait to landscape or vice versa) are the most common configuration changes. However, there are others, such as changes in language/locale, dock status, etc.

The default behavior on a configuration change is that Android destroys and recreates the activity and its contents, to force you to reload your resources, so you get the right ones, such as landscape layouts for the device newly rotated to landscape. While this may seem like a drastic step, it works reasonably well once you get used to it.

There will be some activities where this behavior will harm the *user*. One example would be a camera app, where destroying and recreating the activity could cause problems in getting the preview going again right away. For those cases, Android offers `android:configChanges`: a way to tell Android to *not* destroy and recreate the activity for certain configuration changes. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` says that for two specific types
of configuration change, Android should not destroy and recreate the activity, but instead should just call `onConfigurationChanged()` on the activity instead.

`android:configChanges` should be avoided if at all possible. Partly, that is because you usually need to list *all* possible configuration changes, otherwise you still need to deal with the destroy-and-recreate cycle for the changes you leave out. Partly, that is because the roster of possible configuration changes itself changes, and you may miss those changes and therefore break on newer Android devices. And partly, that is because you, in `onConfigurationChanged()`, have to fix up *everything* with respect to whatever configuration change occurred, and you will forget stuff.

Comment: Thank you. but I still have a question. does it mean that I have to implement `onConfigurationChanged()` in my activity/class?

Comment: @Elpharaoh: If you are using `android:configChanges`, and if there are changes to your activity that are required when the configuration changes, the yes, you will need to override `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Answer (score 2):

When android device changes its configuration like orientation then its screen is redrawn.

if we are defining `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` it means we are telling the device that don't redraw the screen when :

```
1. orientation is changed or.
2. keyboard visibiity is changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevents the activity to be destroyed and created again, as the above answer.
But will do it only when the orientation or the keyboard state changes